# Play! Web Service works if called from actor but not from controller

Tags: web-services, playframework-2.0

In a Play! 2.2.3 app, I need to query web services, retrieve Json responses and process them in different ways (store in db, send emails,...).
I have a specific class with static methods where I use WS API to connect to the web services. Whenever I call this static method from an *Actor* to fetch data from a web service, it works just fine. However, when I call the method from a *Controller*, I get a runtime timeout exception.

Basically, the static method is as follows:

```
public static JsonNode test2() {
    String searchURL = "https://api.angel.co/1/search";
    Promise<WS.Response> promise = WS.url(searchURL)
        .setQueryParameter("query", "medicast")
        .setQueryParameter("type", "Startup")
        .get();

    Promise<JsonNode> promisedJsonNode = promise.map(
        new Function<WS.Response, JsonNode>() {
            public JsonNode apply(WS.Response response) {
                return response.asJson();
            }
        }
    );
    JsonNode angelResp = promisedJsonNode.get();
    return angelResp;       
}
```

I realize I can call web services directly from the *Controller* using *async* but this works only when returning a *Result*, not a *JsonNode*. Given the relative complexity of the methods in the *Controller*; I'd really like to keep the logic of calling web services elsewhere and just call an external static method to get the Json I need. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to get the result of a `Promise<JsonNode>` immediately.  The entire point of Promises is that they *don't* complete right away, they complete *eventually*.

You need to return a `Promise<JsonNode>` from `test2()` instead.  Then, let the caller deal with that promise using map, flatMap, etc. and return a Promise of its own.

Comment: Thks, now it returns a *Promise* and use *async* in the controller to transform the *JsonNode* into a *Result*. It works fine!

Comment: @user3649004 can you post your code sample? I'm unable to achieve the same behavior